# How to generate PWM with duty cycle varying in sinusoidal fashion?

Tags: arduino, pwm, inductor, h-bridge, beaglebone-black

I have to regulate a sinusoidal current in an inductor.

I have only a DC supply.

There are many ways to do it like using stepper motor driver to regulate step wise sinusoidal in 1/256th step mode.

For a specific application, I want to regulate the current by changing the duty cycle of the input PWM to a half-bridge.

If I can generate PWM pulses with a changing duty cycle in sinusoidal way then I'll be able to regulate the current.

I tried using a BeagleBone and an Arduino to generate PWM with a sinusoidal duty cycle, but wasn't able to do that. Mistakenly I had uploaded wrong drawing, now corrected.

[image]

I don't have waveform now to upload. But I can paste the beaglebone code I tried.

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.PWM as PWM 
import time
import math 

Ain1 = "P9_14"
duty=50 # initial value

sin_frequency=100
pwm_frequency=10000
pwm_period = 1.0/pwm_frequency
print("pwm period : ", pwm_period )

PWM.start(Ain1,0)
PWM.set_frequency(Ain1, pwm_frequency)
PWM.set_duty_cycle(Ain1, 0)

count=0
no_pulses=(0.5*pwm_frequency)/(sin_frequency)
print("number of pulses : ", no_pulses)
a=1

while True:
    duty= abs(10.0*math.sin((3.14*count)/(no_pulses)))
    PWM.set_duty_cycle(pin, duty)
    time.sleep(0.1*pwm_period)
    count=count+1
    print(duty)

    if count>=no_pulses:
        count = 0
        duty=0


PWM.stop(Ain1)
pwm.stop(Ain2)
PWM.cleanup()
print("Closed the pwm")
```

Comment: Why weren't you able to that ? Can you post the existing circuit and code as well as any wave forms captured in scope ? Your question contains too few details of things that are already setup and things that have already been tried and their results. Did the beagle bone and arduino setups fail in the same way ? If they did, focus your question to any one of them.

Comment: Are you able generate a pre-determined *steady current* in the inductor with fixed PWM pulse width now ? Why are the inputs to the transistors labelled `HIGH` AND `INPUT PWM` ? Is the top transistor always `ON` ? Then you would be shorting the power supply when the lower transistor turns `ON` during the PWM pulse goes `HIGH` ?

Comment: High mosfet is PMOS so that is always off. When low side NMOS is ON current will build in coil, when OFF current will circulate through the body diode and decay gradually.

Comment: What's the point of the PMOS then?

Comment: You are right. It doesn't need a PMOS. Only a diode would be enough. I am just using body diode of the fet  instead of using a separate diode. Because in design a diode is nothing but body diode of a fet. Since it is PMOS I can tie its gate to supply permanently.

Comment: But your question says, "I have to regulate a sinusoidal current in an inductor." That implies positive and negative half-cycles which, in turn, implies that you need a H-bridge. Meanwhile your code has `PWM = abs(... sin(...) ...)` which suggests that you're trying to do a "full-wave rectified" sine. I think an [edit] might be required.

Comment: For now I coded to get rectified sinwave only. I had plan that if I succeed then I'll use full H bridge and just change the input pin when duty crosses zero.

Answer (score 2):

Your circuit won't work because you have a dead short across your supply: -

[image]

If you want to approach it this way you need to use a full H-bridge: -

[image]

Note that I haven't shown the flyback diodes on the right-side transistors because the bulk diodes in the two MOSFETs serve that purpose.

Of course, if you already have a sinewave signal you could use a PWM modulator such as the LTC6992: -

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andy aka, I'll try this IC and it should do the job. I didn't plan to use discrete components. Was trying to get it done with microcontroller. But this looks simple to me and hopefully would work.

Comment: You also should probably explain a little more about the application. driving a solenoid this way takes some care @AnandYadav